# Average of events/day with a character variable in R

Tags: r, dplyr

So i have a large dataset of meetings for different people in the company. For instance :

| Name | Date |
| --- | --- |
| Erik | 10/03/2021 |
| Erik | 10/03/2021 |
| Erik | 10/03/2021 |
| Erik | 12/03/2021 |
| Erik | 12/03/2021 |
| Maria | 08/03/2021 |
| Maria | 13/03/2021 |

So on March 10th Erik had 3 meetings, and the average of his meetings per day is 5/2 = 2.5

However, i don't know how to compute this with R. I tried the following :

```
df2 <- meetings %>% group_by(date, name) %>% summarise(meeting_count = n())
```

Which gave me that :

| Name | Date | meeting_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Erik | 10/03/2021 | 3 |
| Erik | 12/03/2021 | 2 |
| Maria | 08/03/2021 | 1 |
| Maria | 13/03/2021 | 1 |

But i'm still blocked concerning the methodology to follow in order to obtain the average per day.

Comment: I'd like to obtain a dataset with 2 columns : name and average_meetings_day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>% group_by(Name) %>% summarise(avg_meeting = n()/n_distinct(day(Date)))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  Name  avg_meeting
  <chr>       <dbl>
1 Erik          2.5
2 Maria         1
```

Comment: I thought that it worked but for some of the people the results are weird, for example an average of 85 instead of 6. I'm currently trying to figure out what happens.

Comment: I used df %>% group_by(Name) %>% summarise(avg_meeting = n()/n_distinct((Date))) instead and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `base R`

```
aggregate(Freq ~ Name, subset(as.data.frame(table(meetings)),
       Freq > 0), FUN = mean)
```

-ouptut

```
   Name Freq
1  Erik  2.5
2 Maria  1.0
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
meetings %>% 
    count(across(everything())) %>% 
    group_by(Name) %>%
    dplyr::summarise(n = mean(n))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  Name      n
  <chr> <dbl>
1 Erik    2.5
2 Maria   1
```

#### data

```
meetings <- structure(list(Name = c("Erik", "Erik", "Erik", "Erik", "Erik", 
"Maria", "Maria"), Date = c("10/03/2021", "10/03/2021", "10/03/2021", 
"12/03/2021", "12/03/2021", "08/03/2021", "13/03/2021")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: when i try with dplyr i have the following message : "across function not found", i tried to install dplyr with devtools but it didn't work (package had non-zero exist status). I looked here to convert across : https://rdrr.io/github/tidyverse/dplyr/f/vignettes/colwise.Rmd but i'm not sure to understand well what i have to do.

Comment: @theeconomista can you show your `R version`.  I used `R 4.1.0` and dplyr `1.0.6`

Comment: I use R from Anaconda and my version of dplyr is 0.8.5 so yeah i think i need to update it

Comment: @theeconomista 0.8.5 is old one.  I think `across` etc are after 1.0.0